# Installing PEAR on XAMPP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pear, propel

Attempting to install propel with `PEAR` on `XAMPP`.

This is the error I get when attempting to: `pear install -a propel/propel_generator`

> ERROR: failed to mkdir
>   C:\php\pear\data\propel_generator\lib\behavior

Why would it error out on failing to make a directory?  I attempted to make that directory manually, and install, but it gave me the same error.

Comment: I know there are a number of people who say you should not install Propel from PEAR as the installation process has problems.  Do you still have problems if you follow the manual installation instructions at http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/Installation ?  You still need to install Phing via PEAR, if I remember correctly.

Comment: can you install other packages i.e. from pear, phpunit or phing without problems?

Comment: @Andrew or @cweiske: these two comments make for an answer... get the rep or I'll do it.

Comment: are u on windows or linux ? if on windows forget it

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like your operating system's file permissions are denying access to the directory.

Try editing the permissions for the C:\php directory and allow everyone read and write and then append it to all child directories and give it a try then.

Answer (score 0):

open cmd with "run as administrator"